# MathJax rendered on Hot Network Questions (where it shouldn't)

Tags: bug, mathjax, cross-site

On main page, in the Hot Network Questions, text is automatically converted to MathJax, even if it shouldn't:

[image: overzealous MathJax]

[WordPress.SE doesn't have MathJax enabled](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/220619/globalswp-the-query-vs-global-wp-query), and that question is rendered properly there.

Comment: The question is why shouldn't it be rendered on HNQ?

Comment: This is [a known problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions), and has been reported time and time again on Meta Stack Exchange. It isn't an issue limited to Worldbuiling, so I would have advised sending it there, but it would most likely be closed as yet another duplicate of that question.